# How to get info from iTunes Store

Tags: itunes

how to get information/retrieve data from iTunes Store like this website?

http://app-store.appspot.com/?url=viewTVSeason%3Fid%3D388769641

After search on the net, I get clue that Apple/iTunes Store is not provide API for its content, is it true?

Answer (score 2):

**API Documentation**

PDF http://www.apple.com/itunesaffiliates/API/AffiliatesSearch2.1.pdf

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/blog/introduction---search-api.html

**Example Request**

http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/wsSearch?term=jack+johnson&country=UK

Comment: Thank you powtac,but I can't get the description & review info, I try this example request http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/wsSearch?term=glee+audition&media=tvShow